# How to delete .Trashes/* on NTFS drive on Mac?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, filesystems, ntfs

I installed [Tuxera NTFS for Mac 2013.2](http://www.tuxera.com/products/tuxera-ntfs-for-mac/) on Mac OS X 10.9. I find that `/Volumes/<some NTFS drive>/.Trashes/*` on a NTFS drive I mounted on Mac cannot be deleted.  Any idea?

Things I tried in vain:

- $ rm -rf /Volumes/mydrive/.Trashes/*
- empty trash bin in Dock using GUI

Answer (score 3):

The subfolders in the `.Trashes`-Folder are the Trash-Bins of the users that have logged into the system. Therefore those Trash-Folders belong to the specific users and no one else has a right to access them. So to delete those folders you will have to log in as a System-admin and issue the following command on the Commandline:

```
sudo rm -rf /Volumes/mydrive/.Trashes/*
```

That way the rm-Command will be issued as superuser who is alloewd to remove folders belonging to others.

Those folders will be recreated once the user logs in again! So after you log in as system-administrator there will again be a folder `/Volumes/mydrive/.Trashes/501`.

At least that way it works on a default HFS+-Volume. As NTFS is more restrictive with access-rights you might have to use a different approach.

But why do you want to delete it in the first place? As after emptying the TrashBin the folder is empty it is not really wasting space and as it has a dot in the name it shouldn't even pop up in the UI - even on Windows.

Comment: I just want to empty `/Volumes/<my NTFS partition>/.Trashes/<some folder>`.  When I try `sudo rm -rf /Volumes/<my NTFS partition>/.Trashes/<some folder>`, it gives errors saying `rm /Volumes/<my NTFS partition>/.Trashes/<some folder>: Directory not empty` .   Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Go to the trash folder, go in the deep at the last of the trash directory where you find only files and cannot go deeper, copy and paste some file (e.g. from desktop some .txt file) there. and try to empty trash again.

This worked for me after searching a lot and trying every method including terminal and power shell commands.